# python nested for loop add incremented value by first loop

Tags: python, increment, nested-for-loop

Imagine this situation:

```
cable1 = ['label_11','label_12','label_13']
cable2 = ['label_21','label_22','label_21']
cable3 = ['label_31','label_32','label_33']
cables = [cable1,cable2,cable3]
number = 0

for cable in cables:
    number += 1
    for label in cable:
        if label.find('3') != -1:
            label = str(number)+'_'+label
            print(f'label: {label}')
```

prints:

```
label: 1_label_13
label: 3_label_31
label: 3_label_32
label: 3_label_33
```

instead of:

```
label: 1_label_13
label: 2_label_31
label: 2_label_32
label: 2_label_33
```

How can I make the third iteration over cable to become a 2 label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're increasing the count of variable `number` in each iteration. You can control this increment via flag. Something like this may help -

```
cable1 = ['label_11','label_12','label_13']
cable2 = ['label_21','label_22','label_21']
cable3 = ['label_31','label_32','label_33']
cables = [cable1,cable2,cable3]
number = 1

for cable in cables:
    flag = 0
    for label in cable:
        if label.find('3') != -1:
            label = str(number)+'_'+label
            print(f'label: {label}')
            flag = 1
    if flag:
        number += 1 # only increase the value if the item is found.
```

Comment: Mind the number = 1 before the loops, then this works perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could filter out cables before using your loop:

```
cables = [cable for cable in cables if '3' in ''.join(cable)]
```

Full sample:

```
cable1 = ['label_11','label_12','label_13']
cable2 = ['label_21','label_22','label_21']
cable3 = ['label_31','label_32','label_33']
cables = [cable1,cable2,cable3]
cables = [cable for cable in cables if '3' in ''.join(cable)]
number = 0

for cable in cables:
    number += 1
    for label in cable:
        if label.find('3') != -1:
            label = str(number)+'_'+label
            print(f'label: {label}')

label: 1_label_13
label: 2_label_31
label: 2_label_32
label: 2_label_33
```

Comment: This seams to me the best solution if only one check has to be done. 
In my case I actually need several checks, so the solution of Nk03 suites my case better...

Comment: @novski `[cable for cable in cables if '3' in ''.join(cable)]` can contain serveral checks as well: `[cable for cable in cables if ('3' in ''.join(cable)) | ('2' in ''.join(cable))]` for example

Comment: Fully true! But how to style that line of code is to be questioned.